# Complete Data Likelihood function intuition

Tags: distributions, bayesian, likelihood, expectation-maximization, intuition

I am struggling with the intuition of the following model:

$y_{t} = (1-s_{t})x_{t}'\beta_{0} + s_{t}x_{t}'\beta_{1}+\varepsilon_{t}$   where $\varepsilon_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma{2}$

where $s_{t}$ is an unobserved process which can take the value 0 or 1. It is described by $Pr[S_{t} = 1] = \lambda$ and $Pr[S_{t} = 0] =1- \lambda$.

I understand how we get to the likelihood function:

$p(y|\beta_{0},\beta_{1},\sigma^{2},\lambda) = \prod\limits_{t=1}^{T}(1-\lambda)\phi(y_{t};x_{t}'\beta_{0},\sigma^{2})+\lambda\phi(y_{t};x_{t}'\beta_{0},\sigma^{2})$.

But then I cannot understand why we want the Complete Data Likelihood Function and what the intuition of raising to $s_{t}$ is such that:

$p(y,s|\beta_{0},\beta_{1},\sigma^{2},\lambda) = \prod\limits_{t=1}^{T}[(1-\lambda)\phi(y_{t};x_{t}'\beta_{0},\sigma^{2})]^{1-s_{t}}[\lambda\phi(y_{t};x_{t}'\beta_{0},\sigma^{2})]^{s_{t}}$

I would appreciate some intuition of why we want the complete data likelihood and why in such shape.

Comment: Given $s_t$ is not observable, the last equation has no meaning in the practice. So I guess this equation appeared in the book as an intermediate product, and from here other useful conclusions were derived.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether $s$ is observable or not.

If $s$ is **not observable** (also called latent variable) then the only likelihood you can calculate is the one of $y$. Naturally :

$p(y_t=a)=P(s_t=0)p(x'_t\beta_0+\epsilon=a)+P(s_t=1)p(x'_t\beta_1+\epsilon=a)=(1-\lambda)p(x'_t\beta_0+\epsilon=a)+\lambda p(x'_t\beta_1+\epsilon=a)$

But if $s$ is **observable**, you want to calculate the likelihood of your observation, that is $(y,s)$. This is somehow your output. It would be forgetting information to make yourself blind of something you actually see. Then simply :

$p(y_t=a,s_t=b)=$

- if $b=0$ :  $p(x'_t\beta_0+\epsilon=a,s_t=0)=(1-\lambda)p(x'_t\beta_0+\epsilon=a)$
- if $b=1$ : $p(x'_t\beta_1+\epsilon=a,s_t=1)=\lambda p(x'_t\beta_1+\epsilon=a)$

The final formula is just using powers as a trick to write the two cases as a single formula.

*Notes :*

- *I made conditioning on the parameters implicit in my formulae.*
- *you seemed to assume $s_t$ and $x'_t$ are independent so I did it too.*
- *I use denotation $p(y_t=a)$ instead of $p(y_t)$ for clarity.*